# TestFlight build with multiple versions: is it possible to go back?

Tags: testflight, fastlane

A made a fastlane script to make test flight builds and let's say that at the moment I am working on version 2.5.4 of my app, which is in the app store.

I need to do the following things, in order:

- Make a test flight build for 2.6.0, and have it tested
- Update the test flight version 2.5.4 by making a new build and have it tested
- Make a test flight and an app store build for 2.5.5
- Resume with 2.6.0, make new test flight builds and release it

Now the problem is that the script always fails if I don't increase the version. I didn't try to do it because I am afraid that it will not be possible to go back. Question: if now I make a test flight build for 2.6.0, will it be possible to go back to 2.5.4/2.5.5 or I will be able to change the version only sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

First to make sure we're talking about the same thing:

The AppStore App Version should be 2.6.0 and it has nothing to do with the "testflight build" version. The user sees version 2.6.0 in the application but does not know which build you are using in the background.

Once you upload a "testflight" build, you cannot delete it and you cannot upload another with the same version number, and that is your problem as far as I understand.

What would I do in your place ->
Increment the build number, not the version number, so you can upload the build to testflight and not have to worry about being able to revert to a version.

[image]

I am not sure about the answer to your question, but as far as I know you can go back to the old version, you just cannot upload the same version twice.